# Bluemix の IBM Container の static public IP への課金の確認

Tags: bluemix

コンテナ・サービスの課金単位の一つである Static public IP についてご教示下さい。
無料枠内としては 2つまでという制限がありますが、これには ip request で一時的に取得したアドレスも含まれるのでしょうか。
また、この一時的に取得した ip を確認する方法はありますでしょうか。`cf ic ip list`コマンドでは、パーマネントに利用している ip アドレスしか表示されません。

課金の内容を確認したく、お手数ですが宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

無料枠のパブリックIPの2つのうち、何個使っているかは、Bluemixのダッシュボードから確認できます。下記の例ですと、1IPをリクエストして、それをコンテナに割り当てた状態で、使用状況は1IPとなっています。その後、cf ic ip requestでリクエストすると、使用状況が2IPとなっていましたので、リクエストしただけでもカウントされるのですね。

ダッシュボード上からパブリックIPの使用状況を確認してみてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、Requestしただけの未割り当てのIPを含めてListするには、「cf ic ip list all」コマンドを使用してみてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご丁寧な回答をいただき、大変ありがとうございました。